# How to remove a class from an element on an event added with addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to display images only after they load, using JavaScript.

I tried achieving that by adding a class (*hidden*) to them, then using *addEventListener*, the class is removed after they load.

Here is the code:

```
imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].classList.add('hidden');
    imgs[i].addEventListener('load', this.classList.remove("hidden"));
}
```

After reloading the page, the first image disappears, which indicates that the class was added but something went wrong in the next line.
In the console I get: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined** at that next line.

Comment: The second argument for [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) is a function, not a statement. Wrap your statement in `function () { statement }`.

Comment: Now, I don't get errors, but it still doesn't remove the class!

Comment: Try using Chrome F12 tools to investigate your problem.

Comment: Are you sure the load event is even triggering? Within the function, put `console.log('loaded')` and check your console, or just debug using the developer tools of your favorite browser and put a breakpoint on that line.

Comment: This is generally wrong approach. Read https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/lazy-loading-guidance/images-and-video/ how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot add a load event listener to images already rendered unless it is inline `
2. You cannot add a load event listener to images NOT already present - like a "future" event handler
3. You CAN add the load event handler and then change the source:

```js
// this code runs AFTER the data URI has loaded so it can be simple
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(img) {
  img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    this.classList.remove("hidden");
  });
  img.src = img.getAttribute("data-src");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+P+/HgAFhAJ/wlseKgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Image1" class="hidden" />
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+P+/HgAFhAJ/wlseKgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Image2" class="hidden" />
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+P+/HgAFhAJ/wlseKgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Image3" class="hidden" />
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+P+/HgAFhAJ/wlseKgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Image4" class="hidden" />
```

Comment: The first line helped me understand why I was getting weird and inconsistent results every time I reloaded the page, and based on your code I have achieved what I was looking for, even-though I don't clearly understand why you used the `theImg` variable. Thank you!

Comment: Please see my code. It is much simpler after I made some tests.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you're not using `.addEventListener` correctly. Also, don't use `getElementsByTagName()` as it returns a live node list. Instead, use `.querySelectorAll()`.

Below, 4 different resolutions of the same image are being referenced. You'll see the code working as intended.

```js
imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].addEventListener('load', function(){ 
      this.classList.remove("hidden") 
    });
}
```

```css
img { border:1px solid grey; width:75px; }
.hidden { visibility:hidden; }
```

```html
<img src="http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hvi/uploads/image_file/image_attachment/12710/web.jpg" class="hidden">
<img src="http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hvi/uploads/image_file/image_attachment/12704/large_web.jpg" class="hidden">
<img src="http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hvi/uploads/image_file/image_attachment/12707/print.jpg" class="hidden">
<img src="http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hvi/uploads/image_file/image_attachment/12702/full_jpg.jpg" class="hidden">
```

Comment: I believe this only works if the images take longer to load than to execute the script. If I am wrong I do not understand how your code works